# Centering buttons in a div, not lined up correctly

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem aligning a second set of buttons inside a div for the navigation of my page. There are 2 rows of 3 buttons and the second row is not aligning with the first row. Instead, the first button is aligning with the navigation title instead of aligning with the first button in the first row. I have included all of the html and css, run the code and you will see my problem. Any help with this would be appreciated!

```css
/***********************
NAV PAGE (MAIN)
***********************/

body {
 background-image: url('../img/blue-bg.jpg');
}

.greeting {
 font-family: 'Lemon Normal 400', sans-serif;
 font-size: 45px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: yellow;
 width: 60%;
}

.question {
 font-family: 'Joefin Slab', sans-serif;
 text-align: right;
 color: white;
}

nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: yellow;
}

a .button {
 font-family: 'Cinzel', sans-serif;
 font-size: 25px;
}

.button {
 width: 205px;
 height: 80px;
 margin: 20px 15px 15px 20px;
 border-radius: 30px;
 border: 2px solid yellow;
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(grey, black);
 color: white;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.button:hover {
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(yellow, black);
 color: blue;
}

.cat_title,
.about_title {
 font-family: 'Lemon Mormal 400', sans-serif;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: grey;
}

.nav {
 -webkit-column-count: 2;
 -moz-column-count: 2;
 column-count: 2;
 width: 60%;
 display: inline;
 position: absolute;
 vertical-align: center;
 border-right: 5px solid black;
}

.about {
 -webkit-column-count: 1;
 -moz-column-count: 1;
 column-count: 1;
 width: 35%;
 display: block;
 float: right;
}

.about-me {
 font-family: 'Joefin Slab', sans-serif;
}

p {
 font-size: 16px;
 color: black;
}

footer {
 font-family: 'Joefin Slab', sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Corey's Web Blog!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lemon' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel:900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
      <h1 class="greeting">Welcome to Corey's Blog website!</h1>
      <p class="question">Questions or comments? <a href="avs302003@yahoo.com">Email me!</a></p>
  </header>
  <div class="nav">
    <nav>
      <h1 class="cat_title">Blog Categories</h1>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="sports.html"><button type="button" class="button">Sports</button></a></li>
        <li> <a href="videogames.html"><button type="button" class="button">Video Games</button></a></li>
        <li> <a href="funnystuff.html"><button type="button" class="button">Funny Stuff</button></a></li>
        <br>
        <li> <a href="general.html"><button type="button" class="button">General/Misc.</button></a></li>
        <li> <a href="travel.html"><button type="button" class="button">Travel</button></a></li>
        <li> <a href="technology.html"><button type="button" class="button">Technology</button></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="about">
    <h1 class="about_title">About the Author</h1>
    <img src=""> 
    <p class="about-me">Hello there! My name is Corey Lyons and I'm glad you are visiting my blog page! Feel free to browse the site. I will try to update content once or twice a week. I will find an article on a topic that's under my blog categories and I will do a small one to three paragraph write-up on the subject matter. Now keep in mind this is my opinion and it in no way reflects anyone else's. I understand others will have their own as well. With this in mind, I will try to keep blog posts tasteful and inline. I am interested in building up a portfolio which is how I came up with this idea. Not only that but I also thought it would be a great way to start voicing an opinion more often. I am still learning how to design and develop websites, so I will always be trying to improve this site when I get up to speed with everything!</p>
    <p class="about-me">All of the categories here I will blog about are topics that I enjoy reading about. It wasn't until I got some college under my belt when I realized I was a good writer. Mostly just because I didn't blow off writing assignments and large papers until right before they were due, like I did in high school! Anyways, I hope you will enjoy reading and come back again soon for other future blog writeups!.</p>
  </div>
  <footer>&copy;2014 Corey Lyons</footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're trying to apply columns to the whole `nav` element, which also has the `h1` element. Simply move this part from `nav`

```
nav{ -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;}
```

to

```
nav ul{-webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;}
```

I have added a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vah9n6zx/) so you can see

**EDIT:** Once your question has been answered , I'd suggest to explore the possibility of using another approach instead of your current one. Try ditching the column-count approach and use something like this:

```
nav ul{display:block}
nav ul li{display:inline-block; width:49%}
```

while there will be differences in the order of elements, you'll gain in layout control and responsiveness. Also, you can try using

```
nav ul{
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-align-items: center;
   align-items: center;
   -webkit-justify-content: center;
   justify-content: center;
   -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
   flex-flow: column wrap;
   -webkit-align-content: stretch;
   align-content: stretch;}
```

but this is more complex. anyways, just some food for thought :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no HTML/CSS guru but...

Your h2 title and buttons are all in the same div hence why when the 3 buttons on the left get to the bottom they start again to the right (next to h2 title).

I assume this can be fixed by either creating a h2 div or ensuring the h2 takes up the total width of the nav div so it "forces" the buttons down?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `column-count: 2` from `<div class="nav">`

Apply `column-count: 2` to `<ul>` in `<div class="nav">`

Answer (score 0):

So based on this HTML:

```
<nav>
      <h1 class="cat_title">Blog Categories</h1>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="sports.html"><button type="button" class="button">Sports</button></a></li>
        <li> <a href="videogames.html"><button type="button" class="button">Video Games</button></a></li>
        <li> <a href="funnystuff.html"><button type="button" class="button">Funny Stuff</button></a></li>
        <br>
        <li> <a href="general.html"><button type="button" class="button">General/Misc.</button></a></li>
        <li> <a href="travel.html"><button type="button" class="button">Travel</button></a></li>
        <li> <a href="technology.html"><button type="button" class="button">Technology</button></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

and this CSS:

```
.nav {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    width: 60%;
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: center;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
}
```

You're basically telling the browser: "Take the  element and distribute all of its children across two rows." Since the h1 element is one of the children, it's being rendered with all of the other elements within the nav, and pushing all of your buttons down as a result (hence the unwanted distribution).

The column-count property is handy for rendering blocks of text or even for splitting up lists, etc. It is not usually used for general layout except in special circumstances because it was never designed to handle large scale page layouts where you will have many box-model elements pushing up against many others.

To lay out your menu in the desired way, I would recommend using the flex-box method. Chris Coyier has a wonderful and robust tutorial on the flexbox on this website which you can find here:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I played around with your code using it. It made a lot of other stuff get in the way, that's why so much is changed. The formatting is obviously still off, but I'll let you figure that out - but it DID fix your navigation problem:

```
 <body>
  <header>
      <h1 class="greeting">Welcome to Corey's Blog website!</h1>
      <p class="question">Questions or comments? <a href="avs302003@yahoo.com">Email me!</a></p>
  </header>
  <div class="nav">
    <nav>
      <h1 class="cat_title">Blog Categories</h1>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="sports.html"><button type="button" class="button">Sports</button></a></li>
        <li> <a href="videogames.html"><button type="button" class="button">Video Games</button></a></li>
        <li> <a href="funnystuff.html"><button type="button" class="button">Funny Stuff</button></a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="general.html"><button type="button" class="button">General/Misc.</button></a></li>
        <li> <a href="travel.html"><button type="button" class="button">Travel</button></a></li>
        <li> <a href="technology.html"><button type="button" class="button">Technology</button></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="about">
    <h1 class="about_title">About the Author</h1>
    <img src=""> 
    <p class="about-me">Hello there! My name is Corey Lyons and I'm glad you are visiting my blog page! Feel free to browse the site. I will try to update content once or twice a week. I will find an article on a topic that's under my blog categories and I will do a small one to three paragraph write-up on the subject matter. Now keep in mind this is my opinion and it in no way reflects anyone else's. I understand others will have their own as well. With this in mind, I will try to keep blog posts tasteful and inline. I am interested in building up a portfolio which is how I came up with this idea. Not only that but I also thought it would be a great way to start voicing an opinion more often. I am still learning how to design and develop websites, so I will always be trying to improve this site when I get up to speed with everything!</p>
    <p class="about-me">All of the categories here I will blog about are topics that I enjoy reading about. It wasn't until I got some college under my belt when I realized I was a good writer. Mostly just because I didn't blow off writing assignments and large papers until right before they were due, like I did in high school! Anyways, I hope you will enjoy reading and come back again soon for other future blog writeups!.</p>
  </div>
  <footer>&copy;2014 Corey Lyons</footer>
 </body>


/***********************
NAV PAGE (MAIN)
***********************/

body {
    background-image: url('../img/blue-bg.jpg');
}

.greeting {
    font-family: 'Lemon Normal 400', sans-serif;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: yellow;
}

.question {
    font-family: 'Joefin Slab', sans-serif;
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: yellow;
}

a .button {
    font-family: 'Cinzel', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.button {
    width: 205px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 20px 15px 15px 20px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(grey, black);
    color: white;
}

.button:hover {
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(yellow, black);
    color: blue;
}

.cat_title,
.about_title {
    font-family: 'Lemon Mormal 400', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: grey;
}

.nav {
    border-right: 5px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav ul{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.about {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.about-me {
    font-family: 'Joefin Slab', sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
}

footer {
    font-family: 'Joefin Slab', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}
```

Hope that helps! If you need any more help, just ask. Cheers!

Comment: thanks for the input! I will keep this in mind about the column layout for certain elements